# Angular - $state.go not redirecting as expected when user is not logged in

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to redirect the user to the login page if the user is not logged in. The only use case that I can't get to work is if the user points the browser to a URL that requires authentication.

If the user goes directly to **http://.../index.html#/dashboard** (requires authentication), the browser will attempt to load that page.

If the user first goes to **http://.../index.html#/login** and then replaces 'login' with 'dashboard', the app will correctly not allow that and redirect to the login page.

When the user goes directly to 'dashboard', I can SEE that the code hits the redirection logic, but it seems to just ignore it.

[WAT](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)?

Here's my ui-router config and code:

```
angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngCookies',
    'ui.router',
    'datatables',
    'datatables.bootstrap',
    'angularMoment'
])
    .config(config)
    .run(run);

config.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$httpProvider'];
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login?ac',
            controller: 'LoginController as vm',
            templateUrl: 'app/login/login.view.html'
        })
        .state('content', {
            url: '/',
            abstract: true,
            views: {
                // the main template will be placed here (relatively named)
                '@': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/content-template/container-with-nav.partial.html'
                },
                'navigation@content': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/common/views/master-navigation.partial.html'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('content.dashboard', {
            url: 'dashboard',
            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.partial.html'
                },
                'glance@content.dashboard': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/dashboard-overview.partial.html',
                    controller: 'DashGlanceController as vm'
                },
                'cases@content.dashboard': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/dashboard-cases.partial.html',
                    controller: 'DashCasesController as vm'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('content.casedetails', {
            url: 'case/:caseId',
            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/pages/cases/case.main.partial.html',
                    controller:  'CaseController as vm'
                },
                'casedetails@content.casedetails': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/pages/cases/case.details.partial.html'
                },
                'citation@content.casedetails': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/pages/cases/case.citation.partial.html'
                },
                'payout@content.casedetails': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/pages/cases/case.payout.partial.html'
                },
                'conversation@content.casedetails': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/pages/cases/case.conversation.partial.html'
                },
                'actionpending@content.casedetails': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/pages/cases/case.action-pending.partial.html'
                }
            }
        })
    ;

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
}

run.$inject = ['$state', '$rootScope', '$location', '$cookies'];
function run($state, $rootScope, $location, $cookies) {

    // keep user logged in after page refresh
    $rootScope.globals = ($cookies.get('globals')) ? JSON.parse($cookies.get('globals')) : null;
    console.log('globals (should be set if cookie was present): ', $rootScope.globals);

    if ($rootScope.globals) {
        console.log('Found a cookie for the logged in user: ', $rootScope.globals.currentUser);
    }

    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
        var restrictedPage = $.inArray($location.path(), ['/login', '/register']) === -1;
        var isUserLoggedIn = ($rootScope.globals) && ($rootScope.globals.currentUser) ? true : false;
        console.log('restricted page: ', restrictedPage, ', logged in: ', isUserLoggedIn);

        // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page
        if (restrictedPage && !isUserLoggedIn) {
            // This actually gets entered!
            console.log('Page is restricted and user is not logged in - redirecting to login from listener.');
            $state.go('login', {ac: ''});
            //$location.path('/login');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be because the config is redirecting the user to the new state before your run function has ran when going directly to the restricted state.

The reason is works when they go to login first is because you have already set your event listener and it doesn't get unbound when moving to the new state.

Basically, if you change the listener to the end of state change rather than the start event, it probably will work as the state change will not have ended.

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (event, next, current) {
```

Comment: Thanks, that does work. Is there a way to force the binding of an event prior to ui-router configs kicking in?

Comment: This is the reason the config runs when it does, because it is meant to be a config stage before anything else is ran.